# Why isn't length(self.next) a valid expression in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, data-structures, linked-list

I was defining a class in python that **strictly restricts itself to the innate properties** of a **Singly Linked List**.

`next` is a pointer to the next element.

The complete class:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, v = None):
        self.value = v
        self.next = None
        return

## A function to determine the length of the linked list:
def length(self):
  if self.value == None:
    return(0)
  elif self.next == None:
    return(1)
  else:
    return(1+length(self.next))
```

Why is the expression `1+length(self.next)` not valid? And why do I have to use `1+self.next.length()`?

Comment: Why don't you try it (;

Comment: `self.next` is probably the same object type as `self`. What applies to `self` also applies to `self.next` but you need OO notation because `length()` has only one (implied) argument. so yes `1+self.next.length()`

Comment: `length` is an _instance method_. `length` isn't defined as-is. It needs the object prefix: ex: `self.length()`.

Comment: @MattM. Yeah, I did try. It didn't work. Sorry, but wanted to know why it didn't work, the reasoning. :)

Comment: Without a [mcve], how would we know? And writing your own linked-list class is one of the most useless tasks in Python. There already is a list standard type.

Comment: We have no way of knowing what `self.next` is with only that tiny fragment of code.

Comment: I don't understand all the downvotes, it's clear what the Asker's problem is.  Yes, they are missing the extra 4 lines needed to make it a full example, but seeing how he mentioned it's a linked list you can infer what the missing lines are and answer accoridngly.

Comment: @SubhrajyotiDasgupta for the record, this is too much code.  The ```def __init__(self, v=None):``` method and the ```def length(self):``` are enough

Comment: @user4343502 Okay, Thanks! Will keep in mind the next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is `length`?  `length` does not exist, but `Node.length` does.

The reason `return(1+length(self.next))` doesn't work is because you're calling `length()`, not `Node.length()`.

Instead, try this:

```
return(1+LinkedList.length(self.next))
```

Or this (my preference):

```
return(1+self.next.length())
```